# How to differentiate between a physical checkbox click, and calling setChecked()?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a listview, and each list item contains a checkbox.

My list adapter is re-using Views, as recommended, so it must set the state of the checkbox. It does this by calling `setChecked()`. This causes my `onCheckedChanged()` method to be called. That's fine, but this same method is called when the user physically clicks the checkbox.

The problem here is that I want to do something different, depending on whether the click comes from a physical click, or a programmatic call to `setChecked()`

I thought about overriding `onClick()` and setting a flag in that method, but unfortunately `onClick()` is called **after** `onCheckedChanged()`

So I can post code if required, but the basic question is, how to differentiate between a physical click which changes the checkbox state, and a programmatic checkbox state change?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this in the past is to have a boolean property on the checkbox' owner e.g a form, usually called inhibit.

Then in the event handler exit if it's true, and when I want to set the property programatically set inhibit, change the property, the reset inhibit. PIA but it works.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's kind of where I was going with the boolean flag. But for various reasons this hasn't worked. It would be great if the Android framework supplied an 'event source' parameter to the listener method, like other UI frameworks do, which could be used as a differentiator. If there truly isn't a way to get the framework to distinguish the two situations then I'll have to come up with some really hacky solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was sort of staring me in the face. I've moved some of the code from `onCheckedChanged()` into `onClick()`, which doesn't get called when setting the checkbox state programmatically.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox)view).isChecked();
    if (isChecked) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, it's got one of them. :)